# MySQL GROUP BY & ORDER BY DESC

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a table of checklists.  These checklists have a name, type, version, and release.  The requirement is to group the checklists by name and type, but give the latest release and version and release of that checklist.  Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    c.`name`, c.`type`, c.`ver`, c.`release`
FROM
    reference.checklist c
GROUP BY
    c.`name`
ORDER BY
    c.`name`, c.`ver` DESC, c.`release` DESC
```

The ordering doesn't work when I do it this way.  I get the version and release in ASC order not DESC.  If I remove the GROUP BY clause then the ordering is correct.  Suggestions?  TIA!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you understand the purpose of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to return?  You have several issues here, first you are using `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function on any of your columns in the `SELECT` list, this can cause unexpected results.  I would suggest reading about [MySQL's extension to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: Search this site (and SO) for the `[greatest-n-per-row]` tag.

Comment: I tried changing to DISTINCT(c.`name`), but that doesn't work either.  I want to group all the entries by the name and then only return the latest release/version for that checklist

Comment: @Zane, no, I don't because I'm not a DBA.  And that comment isn't helpful.

Comment: @Slinky33 you don't need to be a dba just do a little research man.

Comment: I've been researching yesterday and today

Comment: See my answer here: [Select the latest changed row in a table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50071/select-the-latest-changed-row-in-a-table/50098#50098)